# Why can't nvidia driver be installed after upgrade to ubuntu 20?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04

Today I have upgraded from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 LTS. During the install I already had an error stating that the installation of the nvidia-driver-435 had failed.

No I have been trying to install it manually, but I get the following error:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-435.21 for kernel 5.3.0-40-generic (x86_64) wo 13 mei 2020  9:43:26 CEST make[1]: Entering directory
'/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic' arch/x86/Makefile:147:
CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support make[1]: /usr/bin/gcc:
Command not found test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e
include/config/auto.conf || (                \ echo >&2;              
\ echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or
include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\ echo >&2 "         Run 'make
oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \ echo >&2
;                                                      \ /bin/false)
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/435.21/build
need-modorder=1 /bin/sh: 1: cc: not found

The C compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' does not appear to be able to create
object files.  Please make sure you have your Linux distribution's
libc development package installed and that '/usr/bin/gcc' is a valid
C compiler name.

*** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***

make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/435.21/build/Kbuild:192:
cc_sanity_check] Error 1 make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1655:
_module_/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/435.21/build] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-40-generic' make: ***
[Makefile:81: modules] Error 2
```

I have tried installing nvidia-driver-440 as well, but with the same result.

When I reboot my screen is not working at all. When I reboot with the previous kernel version, my laptop screen works, but my second monitor does not.

Update:
As one of the answers states, this is a bug. Reverting to nvidia-390 should fix the issue, but in my case hasn't.

Here is the error for installing 390, which is quite similar:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-390.132 for kernel 5.4.0-29-generic (x86_64)
wo 13 mei 2020 11:59:31 CEST
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:147: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
make[1]: /usr/bin/gcc: Command not found
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (                \
echo >&2;                                                       \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";           \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";      \
echo >&2 ;                                                      \
/bin/false)
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.132/build \
single-build= \
need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1
/bin/sh: 1: cc: not found

The C compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' does not appear to be able to
create object files.  Please make sure you have
your Linux distribution's libc development package
installed and that '/usr/bin/gcc' is a valid C compiler
name.

*** Failed CC sanity check. Bailing out! ***

make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.132/build/Kbuild:192: cc_sanity_check] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1719: /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.132/build] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-29-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:81: modules] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Reported as [bug 1860306](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1860306)

From comments:

> This is fixed for nvidia 390 drivers in 390.116 (tested on kernel 5.3.0-26). See [#1851162](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1851162)

So you need to fall back to version 390. The newer versions likely need to be updated and will follow soon.

Comment: I have installed nvida 390. I can now boot with the new kernel, but my second screen is still not working.

Comment: I now see that during the install of 390 driver, I do get the exact same error message.

Comment: Then you need to make sure your system is up to date and if it then still has an error file a bugreport.